Compute d$\omega$ in Cartestian coordinates for a given $\omega$
Define a $2$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$\omega=x\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z+y\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x+z\text{d}x\wedge\text{d}y$$
Compute d$\omega$.
Using the formula for
$$\text{d}\omega=\text{d}u\wedge \text{d}x^i=\sum\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^m}\text{d}x^m\wedge \text{d}x^I$$
for the tensor:
$\omega=\sum_I^\prime\omega_I\text{d}x^{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge \text{d}x^{i_k}$ we get:
$$d\omega=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\text{d}x\wedge(\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z)+\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}\text{d}y\wedge(\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial z}\text{d}z\wedge(\text{d}x\wedge\text{d} y)$$
this gives the $3$-form
$$\text{d}\omega=\text{d}x\wedge\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z+\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x+\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x\wedge\text{d}y$$
Is this the correct path?
Thanks

you can simplify the result a bit

@user8268
I though of using the alternation map, but saw that was not right. There is a sign shift here among the three 3-forms, right? I think it should be $-3(\text{d}x\wedge\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z)$

@Superunknown, for proofs it is helpful to remember the actual alternation map sometimes, for calculations, just recall that you can freely exchange any two adjacent one forms so long as you pick up a minus sign.

@Chris, thanks for the tip.  I notice that shifting the positions of the differentials towards the right does not change the sign, while shifting it towards the left yields a minus sign.

@Superunknown that is is incorrect, shifting in any direction is the same as exchanging two adjacent one forms so you must pick up a minus sign.

@Chris have  look at  p. 5 eqn 17 here: https://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/H185.S11/podrecznik/3forms.pdf

@Superunknown Ok, you have misinterpreted what I said, and I have misinterpreted what you said. You are talking about shifting every one form one place, this is a positive permutation of elements so it does not change sign. What I am saying is taking $dx\wedge dy \wedge dz$ and writing it as $-dy\wedge dx \wedge dz$, i.e. freely exchanging two adjacent one forms.

@Chris OK. You are alternating the sequence, so you get a minus sign, right? However, in the case of the OP, the sequence is not alternated, just shifted, so it should be +  and hence $3(dx\wedge dy\wedge dx)$?

@Superunknown   Recall that 1-forms anticommute pairwise with respect to the exterior product, hence $\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x = -\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}x\wedge\text{d}z = \text{d}x\wedge\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z$, and similarly with the last term, which implies $\text{d}\omega = 3,\text{dvol}_3$ in the end.

@Abezhiko thanks for confirming!

Notice that they used $dz\wedge dx$ in the second term and not $dx\wedge dz$. This way, all three terms come out with $+dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ as the answer.
